# ¿Cómo puedo implementar una relación entre dos clases que no están directamente relacionadas mas que por una tercera clase? (C++)

Tags: c++, poo, relaciones, uml

Estoy un poco confundido tratando de implementar el siguiente problema: Una universidad tiene muchos alumnos, los alumnos tienen muchos cursos; a su vez los profesores también tienen muchos cursos. Necesito que en el programa los profesores sean capaces de asignar calificaciones **en cada curso a cada estudiante** por ejemplo, que un profesor sea capaz de poner calificación a los 3 cursos de un estudiante, y después a los 5 de otro estudiante, y así.
Mi diagrama UML es tal que así
[image: Diagrama UML del problema]

Sin embargo, no creo que esté bien porque no soy capaz de pensar una forma de implementar lo que estoy comentando. He tratado de buscar código de algún problema similar al mío, pero siempre hay solo dos clases: Alumno y Curso, y yo necesito tres (o incluso cuatro si es que es necesario la existencia de la clase de agregación).

¿Me podrían dar ideas para implementar lo que comento y algún tip para mejorar mi diagrama UML?

Comment: Parece más un problema de base de datos.

Comment: Pero ese diagrama UML lo has creado tu o te lo han dado para que lo implementes?

Comment: También me comentaron que sería más adecuado usar base de datos, pero no sé nada de ellas y sí, yo creé ese diagrama pero siento que no es eficiente para la implementación

Answer (score 0):

Debido a que la relación entre la clase `Student` y `Course` es de muchos a muchos (Muchos estudiantes pueden matricular muchos cursos), una posible solución es crear una nueva clase encargada de guardar la inscripción de un estudiante a un curso, y que tenga también como atributo la respectiva nota del estudiante, quedando de la siguiente manera:

[image: Diagrama UML]

De esta manera, la clase `Enrollment` solucionaría el inconveniente presentado, haciendo que cada estudiante pueda tener una nota en un respectivo curso.